# check.Renviron being ignored (OSX + R 2.15)

Tags: r, build, package

The semester has ended and I'm now bringing some packages up to R 2.15 (I did not want to change them while students were using them).  So I'm doing my usual thing, which worked under R 2.14.  As far as I can see, the documentation has not changed with respect to any of this, but I may have missed it.

I have edited my package `ChemoSpec` but when I go to check it, R gives an error about `packages required but not available`, then lists them.  These packages are available, they are in a local directory which is pointed a-:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/Users/bryanhanson/R_pkgs"                                      
[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library"
```

The allegedly missing packages are in fact in `/Users/bryanhanson/R_pkgs`.

I am aware my `.Rprofile` is skipped by the checking process, so the `.libPaths` are not being set by `.Rprofile`  Instead, I have a `check.Renviron` file which is located in `/Users/bryanhanson/.R` and contains the following lines:

```
# Bryan's check.Renviron for customizing check environment
# resides in /Users/bryanhanson/.R
R_LIBS = /Users/bryanhanson/R_pkgs
```

I have tried to check with the following commands in the terminal

```
R --as-cran CMD check ChemoSpec
R --vanilla CMD check ChemoSpec
```

The response to each of these is slightly different, but both fail because of not finding the dependencies, because, apparently, R is not looking in `/Users/bryanhanson/R_pkgs` even though I think I have told it do so.

Any suggestions?  It must be something simple.

Here is the sessionInfo():

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sos_1.3-1  brew_1.0-6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `check.environ` seems to be confined to the usage of package `rcmdcheck` which is an add-on package, so not contained in the base distrubtion of R.

See `?rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck` at the very bottom:

> Note that Config/rcmdcheck/ignore-inconsequential-notes and the
> check.env file are only supported by rcmdcheck, and running ⁠R CMD
> check⁠ from a shell (or GUI) will not use them.

Comment: Good find.  Points for tenaciousness!